# How do I work with WatiN and JQuery tabs?

Tags: jquery, watin

I am having problems syncing WatiN with my company's application.  I am wondering if anyone else has run into these problems.  The program is written in .Net and makes heavy use of JQuery.  The program uses JQuery's tabs, which I am not able to work with.  If I use WatiN to enter the form,  WatiN can work with all the fields for the initial tab, but I do not know of any way to to have WatiN go to  or see what is in the other tabs.  There is also a slight oddity in that when WatiN opens the form and I go to the form and manually press the cancel or save buttons, there is no response.  If I enter the form manually, the buttons work just fine.

Comment: Is it possible to share a link to a similar kind of an application?

Comment: In order to work with the browser dom you need to load the page, when you navigate between the tabs this trigger page load. After page load you can use watin to perform actions or verify the loaded data.

Answer (score 0):

Switching between tabs depends on which JQuery tab implementation is being used.  Below are a couple working examples; basically you click the link then wait for the corresponding div to become visible.  Lots of ways to accomplish this.  You may need to wait on additional or different elements depending on your content (meaning: how AJAX-y), or possibly not at all; it all depends on your specific page behavior.

**Example 1** - JQuery UI

```
IE browser = new IE();
browser.GoTo("http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/default.html");

browser.Link(Find.ByText("Proin dolor")).Click();
browser.Div(Find.ById("tabs-2")).WaitUntil("classname", "ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom");

browser.Link(Find.ByText("Aenean lacinia")).Click();
browser.Div(Find.ById("tabs-3")).WaitUntil("classname", "ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom");
```

**Example 2** - JQuery For Designers

```
IE browser = new IE();
browser.GoTo("http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/tabs.html");

browser.Link(Find.ByText("Second")).Click();
browser.Div(Find.ById("second")).WaitUntil("style", "display: block;");

browser.Link(Find.ByText("Third")).Click();
browser.Div(Find.ById("third")).WaitUntil("style", "display: block;");
```

Both examples are tested and working on WatiN 2.1, IE9, Win7.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The problem is that, although the tabs can be seen in the browser, they are not in the WatiN list of links.

Comment: A guess would be that the tables are in a panel, iFrame, or the like which is causing you to not be able to "see" them.  Dig through the resultant page HTML (Firebug in FF, F12 Dev Tools in IE, etc) at the page structure.